# how can i fetch a normal String to the data in Vue?

Tags: json, vue.js, frontend, fetch, vue-component

I am calling the following backend  String :
`"hello there"`

And as a frontend i am using Vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "test",
  data() {
    return {
      r:'',
      msg: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadMsg() {

    },
  },
  mounted () {
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/msgs/1", requestOptions)


        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => result.forEach(msg=> {
          this.msg.push(msg)
        }) )
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
};
</script>
```

but I am getting the following error:
`error SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0`

However, when I use console.log() I get the massage on the console as expected.

What I want is just to pass the string to the `data()` to `this.msg`
so is there any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: It's not what you say, the response is not `"hello there"` (with quotes) but `hello there` (without quotes), it's not valid json

Comment: The response is hello there without quotes
but the string I am calling from the backend has quotes.
However, do you have an idea or an approach how to pass the string to this.msg or resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only call `.json()` in a JSON response, apparently, your response is just plaintext

And another problem, your `msg` is a `string` (you are initializing it as ''), but the `.push()` is an Array method

Comment: Regardless the method  ```.push()```
is there any way how to pass the string to ```this.msg``` ?

Comment: `this.msg = msg` ?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the content is `hello there` without quotes, the response not valid JSON, this will result in an error when a response is parsed.

`response.text()` should be used instead of `response.json()`.